# Visual Studio command to connect to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am working on a lot of different Team Projects and TFServers. Unfortunately the Visual Studio "Team Explorer" does provide little comfort in managing a large amount of servers and projects. I am looking for a way to:

- Set my *favorite* connections to a button or similar
- Optional: Search within my *bookmarked* connections
- Optional: Having more than a maximum of 8(?) Team Projects per server

I tried to create Visual Studio short cuts when starting devenv.exe and to configure a custom button. But the available commands do not provide the possibility to pass any connection, or I did not find it.

So I thought of writing an add-in which could extend the Team Explorer and implement my optional requirements listed above as well. But I did not find any API which allowed me to do so. Does it not exist or was I searching in the wrong place?

If there is no way, then the only possibility would be a complete rewrite of Team Explorer Features, which is far to much what I had initially planned. Maybe anyone has ideas, knows some API, or other tools which already exist for my intentions.

I use Visual Studio 2013, there are plans to use 2017 at the end of the year.

Comment: for extending Team Explorer Did you try these links [link1](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Extending-Explorer-in-9dccd594) and [link2](https://binary-stuff.com/list/visual+studio+plugin)

Comment: thanks for giving me direction, however it took me some time to find the correct service - i was looking for some connection, however by debugging I found that Team Explorer sets [a context via a service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn235467(v=VS.120,d=hv.2).aspx) in order to change the connection

Answer (score 0):

The only way is customizing Team Explorer. Could not directly add an extension or "button".

You could also add a uservoice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.